# jQuery Ajax Post request failing to send data to nodejs server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, rest

I'm creating a video streaming site that keeps the backend informed about the video's play status. However when I try to send the data using an ajax request it it showing up as an empty object `{}` on the backend:

Client code

```
data = JSON.stringify({"fish":"pope"})
datasize = data.length
$.ajax({
    dataType:"json",
    type: "POST",
    url:'http://localhost:8080/',
    body: data,
    success: function(data) {console.log('foobar');}
});
```

Serverside:

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

I've tried putting the data in the `data` reference also which gives `undefined` as the output on the server, and setting content-length which is dissallowed. I've also set Access-Control-Allow-* options, and it's working fine when sending requests with Postman.

EDIT: Debug output from browser

[image: Debug output from browser]

Comment: `console.log(req.body)` should be above, as `res.sendStatus` ends the request

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I don't think that is the issue, as the code is working fine with Postman. I made the change you suggested and got the same output. I should have mentioned the above code prints an empty object `{}` not nothing. Shall edit

Comment: According to the [`documentation`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), the parameter `body` should be `data`, hence its not able to send the request body

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I tried this and mentioned the output in the original question.

Comment: Go to postman tool, navigate to Code button Below send button, Postman will scaffold a code in your preferred lanaguage, select jQuery and check with your existing code what went wrong

Comment: If sending json and expecting json at server you also need to set appropriate contentType. If you are expecting form encoded data at server then don't stringify the object and $.ajax will set default contentType

Comment: @KunalMukherjee that has worked beautifully! Postman version was completely differently formatted but using that method works. If you want to answer with that, I'll edit in the code I used to your answer and mark it an answered.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the advise of a commenter, I used the code generated by POSTMan, which seems to work well. I give it below.

```
var settings = {
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({"foo":"bar"}),
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```